# Multiple UITableViewCell creation through GCD before reloading the UITable view

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, uicollectionviewcell

```
dispatch_queue_t  backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);//
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
                NSLog(@"BackgroundQueue-makeUpcomingCell");
                // storeLiveAndUpcomingMatches
                [[TVStoredData sharedInstance] makeRunnningCell];
                [[TVStoredData sharedInstance] makeUpcomingCell];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    NSLog(@"MainQueue-makeUpcomingCell");
                    [tblView ReloadData];
                });
            });
```

I am trying above code to create the multiple cell without main thread through GCD and before reloading the Table view. These cells are created successfully but when these are returned in cellforRowatIndexpath than only image views of cells are showing not any label and buttons are visible in cell.

I scroll the table in next 15-20 sec, than suddenly all labels and buttons start to visible.

It seems like store cells in array taking some to initiate its controllers.

Comment: It seems like store cells in ARRAY taking some to initiate its controllers. Please suggest me over this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can not update UI in other thread then main.

**2)** You are using strong variable into blocks.

Comment: Thanks Retro..
I debug the code in cell for row at index path and there all the controllers available but not visible in cell.  and after 15-20 sec start to visible.

Comment: Because your UI code is not running into Main thread, whats the motive of this approach?

Comment: If UI code is not running than How can UIImageView show the image just after reloading the TAbleView.

Comment: if UI code is not running than why UIImageView appearing just after reloading the table. while other labels and buttons come in next 15-20 sec.

Comment: I am saying its not running in Main thread so may take uncertain time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified, all of UIKit (and this would certainly include `UITableViewCell`) should be considered "main thread only." If you have some expensive work to do in order to generate the cells (download an asset, render an image, etc), you can ship that work to the background with GCD, but constructing the `UITableViewCell` instances themselves should be done on the main thread.